# why my filter always return nothing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angular filter, when i use it, he always return nothing,  but I have a condition suitable values

```
$scope.seasonIncludes = [];
     function changeInputState(event) {
                angular.element(event.target).toggleClass('active');
            }


        $scope.includeSeason = function(season, event) {

                    $scope.seasonIncludes = []
                    $scope.seasonIncludes.push(season.season_number);
                    changeInputState(event)
                };

        $scope.seasonFilter = function(series) {
                        if ($scope.seasonIncludes.length > 0) {
                            if ($.inArray(series.season.season_number, $scope.seasonIncludes) < 0) return;
                        }

                        return $scope.series;
                    };      
    }]);
```

Comment: Because your filter return nothing. That's why

Comment: @AlonEitan how i can fix it?

Comment: `if ($.inArray(series.season.season_number, $scope.seasonIncludes) < 0) return;` I'll start by checking this condition always evaluated as `true`, or check why i'm returning `$scope.series` and not part of the `series` passed to the function

Comment: @AlonEitan can you explain me how to return part of series?

Comment: Don't know what part to return, so I can't. Are you sure the function is returning from this line `return $scope.series;`? Maybe it actually return from here: `if ($.inArray(series.season.season_number, $scope.seasonIncludes) < 0) return;`?

Comment: Show all relevant code and provide explanation of what you expect this filter to do. See [mcve]